# How to detect SqlDependency is broken for an application?

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqldependency

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that creates a `SqlDependency` with SQL Server.

When records are inserted into a table, the `SqlDependecy` fires an `OnChange` event to inform the application. Each time this change event is fired, I recreate the `SqlDependency`.

But when I bulk insert records into the table, the `SqlDependency` is removed from the table.

```
select * from sys.dm_qn_subscriptions
```

shows no entries for the subscription in the `sys.dm_qn_subscriptions` management view.

I want to detect in my asp.net application when there is no subscription for query notification; then the application should re-register itself with SQL Server.

Please help me how to re-register application